# Check Status of Linked Server Databases

Tags: sql-server

I want to write a script to query all the databases on the linked Servers and their Status.. 'online' or 'offline'.
Here you will have to program with variables and cursors as well as establish the connection to linked servers in order to read view there.

The results should look like this.

```
Server        DBName          Status
XYZ           ABC             Online
XFD           NDH             Offline 
etc...
```

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service. Take the [tour], read [ask] and then *attempt to solve the problem yourself* before posting a [mcve] explaining what specific issues you are encountering.

Comment: Why would you need a `CURSOR` to check if the database is online or not? Why not just use the `state` or `state_desc` column in  the `sys.databases` object?

Answer (score 1):

As I mention, it would seem far easier to use the `sys.servers` object, along side the `sys.databases` object. You can use Dynamic SQL to create a large `UNION ALL` query to do this:

```
USE master;
GO

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SET @SQL = STUFF((SELECT  @CRLF +
                          N'UNION ALL' +  @CRLF + 
                          N'SELECT N' + QUOTENAME(s.[name],'''') + N' AS ServerName,' + @CRLF +
                          N'       d.[name] AS DatabaseName,' + @CRLF +
                          N'       d.[state] AS DatabaseState' + @CRLF +
                          N'FROM ' + CASE s.is_linked WHEN 1 THEN QUOTENAME(s.[name]) + N'.' ELSE '' END + N'master.sys.databases d'
                  FROM sys.servers s
                  FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,13,'') + N';'

--PRINT @SQL; --Your Best Friend

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```

This **assumes** all the linked server are accessible (if they aren't, that's a different problem you need to fix).

I return the value of `state`, which uses the following statuses ([sys.databases (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-databases-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)):

> 0 = ONLINE
>   1 = RESTORING
>   2 = RECOVERING | SQL Server 2008 through SQL Server 2017
>   3 = RECOVERY_PENDING | SQL Server 2008 through SQL Server 2017
>   4 = SUSPECT
>   5 = EMERGENCY | SQL Server 2008 through SQL Server 2017
>   6 = OFFLINE | SQL Server 2008 through SQL Server 2017
>   7 = COPYING | Azure SQL Database Active Geo-Replication
>   10 = OFFLINE_SECONDARY | Azure SQL Database Active Geo-Replication

If you want the word, use `state_desc`.

Comment: Msg 7416, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Access to the remote server is denied because no login-mapping exists.

Comment: But the coe is very helpful thanks, guess i Need to get Access to the linked Servers .. thanks lamu. you the best

Comment: Like I said, I assume the server are accessible, thats a different problem you need to fix, @OusainouSecka .

Comment: yeah true, the Servers are accessible. Any idea what the Problem could be @lamu

Comment: *"the Servers are accessible"* not to you, @OusainouSecka *"Access to the remote server is denied because no login-mapping exists"*

Comment: Thanks @lamu. appreciated

Comment: I found the Problem. Two of the remote Servers i did not have Access to, however isolated it in the Code using where clause: Now all working fine: Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hallo @lamu, Is is possible to use a error handler to catch not connected linked Servers in the Code above

Comment: Not as it is written, no. You would have to change the code to use `TRY.. CATCH` syntax and `INSERT` the values into a (temporary) table.

Comment: Hallo lamu, I tried add temp table to log error Messages and also a try - catch Syntax to catch Errors and continue Looping but to no avail.

Comment: It's still La`rn`u, @OusainouSecka .